# C# Deleting Rows from DataGridView and Updating Database

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, rows

I am trying to create an application that will contain a DataGridView with data bound to a DataSource. I use the fill method on Form_Load and I would like to know how do I delete one or more checkboxed rows, not only from my table but also from the database/datasource at the same time.

I use this code on the delete button, but it doesn't remove permanently the selected rows. Any help?

```
for (int i = 0; i < Products.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridViewRow dr = Products.Rows[i];
    if (dr.Selected == true)
    {
        Products.Rows.RemoveAt(i); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to make a database call to delete selected rows.

Comment: The database already exists and it is loaded when the application runs. The problem is, when deleting 1 or more checkboxed rows, via "Delete" button, those rows disappear but will be back again if i restart the program. Any ideas how do i update those changes on the database?

Comment: Can you specify what database you are using. MS SQL Server or MySQL or Oracle etc.?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is removing the selected rows from the `DataGridView` only.

You are not making any database call to delete the rows.

I assume you are using Microsoft SQL server.

In that case you will need to get the something that uniquely identifies product. For example Product Id.

Assuming you've got your `ProductId` column from the database bound to some column in `DataGridView`.

Your code should be like below.

```
//string variable to capture product Ids for selected products
System.Text.StringBuilder productIds = new System.Text.StringBuilder(string.empty);

for (int i = 0; i < Products.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridViewRow dr = Products.Rows[i];

    if (dr.Selected == true)
    {
        Products.Rows.RemoveAt(i);

        productIds.Append(productIds.length > 0 ? "," + Convert.ToString(dr["ProductId"]) : Convert.ToString(dr["ProductId"]));
    }
}

DeleteProducts(productIds.ToString());
```

Now your `DeleteProducts` method should be as below.

```
private int DeleteProducts(string productIds)
{
    int recordsDeleted = 0;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Your connection string here"))
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Your SQL Stored Procedure name here", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter paramProductIds = new SqlParameter("@productIds", varchar(2000));
                paramProductIds.Value = productIds;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramProductIds);

                conn.Open();

                recordsDeleted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        finally { conn.Close(); }

    }

    return recordsDeleted;
}
```

And your stored procedure should be as below (Assuming MS SQL Server).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteProducts
    @productIds VARCHAR(2000)
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Products WHERE ProductId IN (SELECT item FROM dbo.Split(',', @productIds))
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the necessary call to your DB manager. If you're using MYSQL, then you could use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Products.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridViewRow dr = Products.Rows[i];
    if (dr.Selected == true)
    {
        Products.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
        // CODE ADDED
        MySqlCommand cmd = sql.CreateCommand(); // creates the MySQL object needed for queries (I think there's another way also, but I use this)
        cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id = 1"; // sets the query

        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // executes the query
        }
        catch( MySqlException e )
        {
            sql.Close();
            Console.WriteLine( e.Message );
        }
        sql.Close();
        // CODE ADDED
    }
}
```

`sql` was defined before as `MySqlConnection sql`, and it's initialization was:

```
try {
    sql = new MySqlConnection( {SQL_CONNECTION_STRING} );
    try
    {
        sql.Open();
        sql.Close(); // Close the DB. This block is useful to check whether or not the connection was successfully opened
    }
    catch ( MySqlException e )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( e.Message );
    }
}
catch ( MySqlException e )
{
    Console.Write( e.Message );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Confirm ?","DELETE", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    string name = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[WHEREINDEX].Value.ToString();
    sql = "DELETE FROM [TABLE] WHERE [id] = " + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[WHEREINDEX].Value.ToString();

    if (db.Exec(sql) > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(name + " deleted");
        dtSummary.Rows.Find(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString()).Delete();
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error while deleting") 
    }
}
```